# What were some of the conceptual revolutions caused by Newton's work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, history

Newton's publication of the Principia caused a conceptual revolution through all of science. I know about two interesting demonstrations of that:

1. The rejection of common sense and intuitive reasoning in favor of mathematically stated theories, tested against physical observations,  which became standard in all of science.
2. The understanding that celestial bodies obey the same basic laws as everyday objects here on earth.

I wonder what are some other interesting examples to concepts or beliefs revolutionized by Newtonian mechanics, specifically ones that shed light on the "old" way of thinking about nature. I found nothing but long books about the Newtonian revolution but I'm looking for something a bit more concise.

Comment: Would [hsm.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Huygen's Wave Theory of Light stood for quite some time before Newton claimed that light was made up of particles called corpuscles, and people believed in his idea for quite sometime before the Double Slit experiment and the other experiments that hinted at light's wave nature were performed.